# React component overlap each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, overlapping

component `Publisher.js` and other child components `projectStatus.js` are overlapping each other when Render the Child component. I don't know what's going wrong and how to fix this. You can see the image
[image: Component overlaping each other]
[image]

this is my `Publisher.js`

```js
//import useState hook to create menu collapse state
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {NavLink, Outlet} from "react-router-dom"

//import react pro sidebar components
import {
  ProSidebar,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  SidebarHeader,
  SidebarFooter,
  SidebarContent,
} from "react-pro-sidebar";

//import icons from react icons
import { FaFileContract } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiLogOut} from "react-icons/fi";
import { HiDocumentReport } from "react-icons/hi";
import { BiCog } from "react-icons/bi";
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";


//import sidebar css from react-pro-sidebar module and our custom css 
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import "./publisherCss.css";


const Publisher = () => {
  
    //create initial menuCollapse state using useState hook
    const [menuCollapse, setMenuCollapse] = useState(false)

    //create a custom function that will change menucollapse state from false to true and true to false
  const menuIconClick = () => {
    //condition checking to change state from true to false and vice versa
    menuCollapse ? setMenuCollapse(false) : setMenuCollapse(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="sidebarHeader">
          {/* collapsed props to change menu size using menucollapse state */}
        <ProSidebar collapsed={menuCollapse}>
          <SidebarHeader>
          <div className="logotext">
              {/* small and big change using menucollapse state */}
              <p>{menuCollapse ? "Evc" : "Publisher "}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="closemenu" onClick={menuIconClick}>
                {/* changing menu collapse icon on click */}
              {menuCollapse ? (
                <GiHamburgerMenu/>
              ) : (
                <GiHamburgerMenu/>
              )}
            </div>
          </SidebarHeader>
          <SidebarContent>
            <Menu iconShape="square">
            <NavLink to="/publisher/projectstatus">   <MenuItem  icon={<FaFileContract />}>Project status</MenuItem>  </NavLink>
              <MenuItem  icon={<HiDocumentReport />}>All project</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem  icon={<BiCog />}>Settings</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </SidebarContent>
          <SidebarFooter>
          <NavLink to="/login">
            <Menu iconShape="square">
              <MenuItem icon={<FiLogOut />}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            </NavLink>
          </SidebarFooter>
        </ProSidebar>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default Publisher;
```

```
Publisher.css
```

```css
#sidebarHeader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    display: flex;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    /* position: absolute; */

  }
  #sidebarHeader .closemenu {
    color: rgb(0,7,61);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    top: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout .logotext p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul {
    padding: 0 5px;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item {
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper {
    background-color: #fbf4cd;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper .pro-item-content {
    color: #000;
  }
  #sidebarHeader .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout .active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #fece00 0%, #ffe172 100%);
  }
  #sidebarHeader .logo {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }

 .nav-link .active{
      background-color: #ffe172;
  }
```

I think I am doing some wrong CSS override property but I am unable to understand what's wrong I am doing. if anyone know please correct me

if anyone knows how to fix this please tell me. it's appreciated

**update:**

After updating the `CSS` `display: flex` it show the child content in flex but the problem is, I specified `width: 220px` for the sidebar but the  **child** content not go above the `220px` width. you can see the image.
Now how can I fix this to a child can use width?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is not complete, most likely it's styles or wrong location of "Outlet". I made simplified [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-platform-2wf5rq?file=/src/index.js), I hope it helps.

Comment: hey buddy can you tell me what changes you do? and I have also Style folder but I don't know what I doing wrong

Comment: Moved "Outlet" to flex container `<div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100vh', overflow: 'scroll initial' }}>`. Well, I don't have styles.

Comment: Actually, I am facing the issue in the `publisher.js` component but I accidentally provide the `Admin.js` code can you please check my updated code and tell me what I doing wrong

Comment: Use instead of fragments "div" with "display flex", "sidebarHeader" needs to be removed from absolute positioning

Comment: I do not understand what you trying to tell. can you please tell me in detail or with code

Comment: I suggest you make sandbox and reproduce problem, I guess what's wrong